# Nuxt New Components not Hot Reloading / Compiling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Facing a weird behavior lately.
Created a new Nuxt.js app and some of the components I create are just not hot reloading. When I stop the dev server and recompile with `npm run dev` I can see the changes in the browser but they are just not hot reloading whenever I save while the dev server is running. This is just happening to a few of the components I create which makes it even more annoying.

What I've tried so far:

- checking my user has all required r/w Rights in the folder
- tried different nuxt versions
- created a blank nuxt project

Comment: What os? Is it run via docker?

Comment: MacOS, nope not via docker. Just created another brand new project and it's working as expected for now. But still would like to know if anyone ever experienced anything like that before.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're actually saving your files? If it happens for you again just go back to your IDE and press Save again and see if the hot reloading works.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @dmmker999? Currently experiencing this issue...

Comment: Clear the browser cache and try, because some compiled JavaScript might be cached by browser. Just a try

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because of folders names.

If you have something la this:

~/components/Products/ProductsSimple.vue

you must change it to

~/components/products/ProductsSimple.vue

(products folder with lowercase p)

Comment: I was having the same issues, I don't understand why lowercase is making such difference.